# How to use pull queue on dev server of Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

We have been using push queue for a very long time and have no problems in consuming the tasks from a dev server.

However during implementing a new service with pull queue, it became difficult to figure out how to do the same thing on the dev server.

Basically from the docs, what we can see is that you should use a REST api (we can't use the direct queue api as it is consumed by an external app) to lease/delete a task with the end point of

```
https://www.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta1/projects/taskqueues
```

But obviously this will not work in local dev server, and it appears that no place have talking about this.

Just wondering if anyone had ever run into the same issue had can shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pull Queue, task consumer can be [internal](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull#Pulling_Tasks_within_App_Engine) or [external](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull#Pulling_Tasks_from_Outside_App_Engine).

If you need it to work on dev server, then just create a handler (a servlet) and use internal API to [add](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull#Adding_Tasks_to_a_Pull_Queue), [lease](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull#Leasing_Tasks) and [delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull#Deleting_Tasks) tasks.